# Text Object not supported. Java excel API

Tags: java, excel, jxl

I have this piece of code to read from an xls file:

```
fileName = "...."

WorkbookSettings settings = new WorkbookSettings();
settings.setEncoding("Cp1252");

System.out.println("BEFORE");

Workbook w = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(fileName), settings);
Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(1);

System.out.println("AFTER");
```

This is what I get in the console:

```
BEFORE
Warning:  Text Object on sheet "Detalle" not supported - omitting
jxl.common.AssertionFailed
    at jxl.common.Assert.verify(Assert.java:37)
    at jxl.read.biff.SheetReader.handleObjectRecord(SheetReader.java:1811)
    at jxl.read.biff.SheetReader.read(SheetReader.java:1059)
    at jxl.read.biff.SheetImpl.readSheet(SheetImpl.java:716)
    at jxl.read.biff.WorkbookParser.getSheet(WorkbookParser.java:257)
    at MapMovInfoResource.postService(MapMovInfoResource.java:77)
```

The problem comes when I try to open the second sheet in that file. When I use the first sheet (`w.getSheet(0)`), it works fine.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: does you sheet contain any thing other than text?

Comment: @UnniKris it has filters in the first row. But sheet 0 also does and it works when I open that one

Comment: i have added the jxl tag so that the question can get more relevant views. however, you can try POI library for excel manipulation. Haven't used JXL, but POI is also very easy to learn and use.

Comment: @UnniKris thanks! I'm going to try and stick to jxl since it's the library used so far in the project.. I removed the filter row and it seems to work. The odd thing is that other sheets also have filters and works fine...

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tGRT.jpg)

Its seem you have some value in excel which are not text. Please check excel value like in image, and if and special quotes are available then remove that and try again.